# What is the meaning of labels on the lenses, e.g. 12L and 12H on Computar M0814-MP2?

Tags: optics

Computar M0814-MP2 lens comes with small labels attached, e.g. `12H`, `12L` or `15H`:

[image]

[image]

What is the meaning of these labels? I noticed that `12H` and `15H` was on the lens made in Japan, `12L` on the one made in China. Do they indicate factory of origin?

Comment: that looks like a quality inspector tag ... it may also be something that the seller put on

Comment: @jsotola Quality inspection tag sounds plausible. Definitely not a seller's tag. I've seen them on factory new items.